# Mailchimp Ajax subscribe to list

Tags: jquery, ajax, mailchimp

I am trying to subscribe to my Mailchimp list like this

```
<form method="post" action="https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe.json" id="mailChimpForm">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6" data-scrollreveal="enter left after 0s over 1s" data-sr-init="true" data-sr-complete="true">
      <input type="text" name="FNAME" placeholder="Your name (optional)" class="form-control input-box">
   </div>
      <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Your email address" required="required" class="form-control input-box">
   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-primary custom-button green-btn" type="submit" data-scrollreveal="enter right after 0s over 1s" data-sr-init="true" data-sr-complete="true">Sign me up!</button>
</form>
```

The ajax code is this

```
$('#mailChimpForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var payload =   {
        "apikey": "------------",
        "id": "244169",
        "email": {
            "email": "me@example.com"
        },
        "send_welcome": false
    };
    payload = JSON.stringify(payload);

    console.log($(this).attr('action'))

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: payload,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

But I get this error

> https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Can anyone point me in the right direction by telling me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because of this thing called [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Also, it's generally bad practice to include private API keys in client-facing code, like this Javascript you've written.

I'd check out a library like [AjaxChimp](https://github.com/scdoshi/jquery-ajaxchimp). I hope you don't need this answer, and you were able to figure it out, but for all the others...